# Ubuntu 21 black screen on boot after disabling Wayland

Tags: boot, wayland

I was having troubles with Teamviewer, so I disabled Wayland uncommenting the line:
WaylandEnable=false
in  /etc/gdm3/custom.conf .
Then I rebooted and now it shows me a black screen and I can't get the terminal.
I tried:

- ctrl + alt + F1 / F4 to get the terminal
- booting holding shift, or pressing esc

Usually on boot it doesn't show me the grub menu, but goes directly to the login.

I have a Hp Z2 with intel core i7. It had Windows installed, I made a partition and installed Ubuntu.

I hope someone could help me, I'm not an expert at all..

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version. There is no "Ubuntu 21" desktop release.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean Ubuntu 22 instead of Ubuntu 21.

I experience exactly the same issue with yours and managed to solve it by following these steps:

1. Boot ubuntu in advance option > recovery mode.
2. Enable networking
3. Repair broken packages
4. After repair broken packages, Ubuntu will ask to reboot your system. After that, everything is fixed.

I don't know what exactly the problems are, but hopefully this would help you. (At least it solved mine)